# How does $\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2} \frac{1-\cos^2x}{\sqrt{\sin^2(x/2)}}dx$ simplify to $\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2} 4\sin(x/2)\cos^2(x/2)dx$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

$$\int_{\large{\frac{\pi}{3}}}^{\large{\frac{\pi}{2}}} \frac{1-\cos^2x}{\sqrt{\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)}}dx$$

How does the above simplify to the below?

$$\int_{\large{\frac{\pi}{3}}}^{\large{\frac{\pi}{2}}} 4\sin\left(\frac x2\right)\cos^2\left(\frac x2\right)dx$$

I suspect it has something to do with a double angle or half-angle identity, but I don't know where the $4$ came from, and I am not sure how the $\sin\left(\frac x2\right)$ made its way to the numerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int_{\large{\frac{\pi}{3}}}^{\large{\frac{\pi}{2}}} 4\sin(x/2)\cos^2(x/2)dx=\int_{\large{\frac{\pi}{3}}}^{\large{\frac{\pi}{2}}} \frac{4\sin^2(x/2)\cos^2(x/2)}{\sin(x/2)}dx$$

$$I=\int_{\large{\frac{\pi}{3}}}^{\large{\frac{\pi}{2}}} \frac{\left[2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)\right]^2}{\sin(x/2)}dx$$

$$I=\int_{\large{\frac{\pi}{3}}}^{\large{\frac{\pi}{2}}} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\sin(x/2)}dx$$
$$I=\int_{\large{\frac{\pi}{3}}}^{\large{\frac{\pi}{2}}} \frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{\sqrt{\sin^2(x/2)}}dx$$

I used $2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)=\sin(x)$ and $1=\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{\sin^2 x}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{\left(\color{red}{2}\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}=\color{red}{4}\cos^2\frac{x}{2}\sin\frac{x}{2}.$$